# LaTeX is saying I'm in draft mode when I'm not

Tags: errors, draft

This is driving me insane now. I keep getting the following error code when trying to insert an image. It states that I'm in draft mode, when I'm not.  I've tried following previous advice, but this is what I keep getting.[image: Input]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you compile the correct document? I had a similar problem once: My editor (Texmaker) was compiling a different document because I set it as a so-called master document and forgot about it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Do you mean document class?  I'm very new to LaTeX, so you'll have to bear with me.

Comment: Where do you see something about draft mode? I only see that a graphic is not found.

Answer (score 3):

The error message just says, that image file `Kettle.JPG` is missing. Check the spelling (e.g., lower-/uppercase matters) and location of the image file.

Draft mode is *not* enabled. Package `graphics`/`graphicx` only writes a *warning*, if the image file cannot be found and option `draft` is active.

Some remarks to the source code snippets in the screen shots:

- `\bf` is deprecated, use `\textbf{...}` instead.
- Don't use `\\` at the end of paragraphs. They cause the "Underfull `\hbox`" warnings. `\\` is macro for a new line, it ends the old line and starts a new one that must not be an empty line (end of paragraph).
- If you want to have space between paragraphs without indentation of the first line, take a look at package `parskip`.
- Math equations, see package `amsmath` and its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf).
- Tables: much less lines are usually better, see package `booktabs` and its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf).
- Numerated lists are handled by environment `enumerate` in LaTeX. For additional packages, see CTAN topic [`list-enum`](http://ctan.org/topic/list-enum).
- Floating environments `table` are used to keep the text body in the middle of the page intact. Option `h` should only be used in emergency cases. `\includegraphics` can also be used outside of `figure`. The caption title "Graph" does not provide much information anyway.
- ...

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The title "Graph" was used as a working title while I was trying to sort this problem.  I've added the screenshot for the draft problem.  So much to learn about LaTeX, but I'm trying!